# Where do I find Activiti 7 core API documentation?

Tags: activiti

I am developing an application which embeds Activiti core 7. Unfortunately, I could not find any java doc nor proper guide on activiti.org. The only information I could find was sample codes. I downloaded source code from GitHub and tried to build javadoc. However, I did not work either. Is there any place where I can find some reference documentation as well as Java doc?

Comment: You can take help from https://www.activiti.org/userguide/ . here most the things are given. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. The link you provided (activiti.org/userguide) is based on Activiti 6.0 and not Activiti 7.0.

Comment: user1250720  There is no major changes happen between these releases.You can refer .

Answer (score 1):

**Activiti 7** documentation moved to **gitbook** , which can be accessible from [**here**](https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/).

Activiti 7 supports cloud deployment via it's **Activiti Cloud**.